# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints. SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am not sure as to why I am experiencing this error as I do not have any view modifiers on any of my linked views, and yet I have this error:

> 

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000003807d0 'accessoryView.bottom' _UIRemoteKeyboardPlaceholderView:0x7fc40b6609d0.bottom == _UIKBCompatInputView:0x7fc40b577c70.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000003be350 'assistantHeight' SystemInputAssistantView.height == 45   (active, names: SystemInputAssistantView:0x7fc40b5050a0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000380aa0 'assistantView.bottom' SystemInputAssistantView.bottom == _UIKBCompatInputView:0x7fc40b577c70.top   (active, names: SystemInputAssistantView:0x7fc40b5050a0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000380af0 'assistantView.top' V:[_UIRemoteKeyboardPlaceholderView:0x7fc40b6609d0]-(0)-[SystemInputAssistantView]   (active, names: SystemInputAssistantView:0x7fc40b5050a0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000380af0 'assistantView.top' V:[_UIRemoteKeyboardPlaceholderView:0x7fc40b6609d0]-(0)-[SystemInputAssistantView]   (active, names: SystemInputAssistantView:0x7fc40b5050a0 )>
```

My SwiftUI Views are as follows:

> 

```
struct RecordView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var modelView : JournalRecordsModelView
    
    @State private var navigationPath: [JournalRecordsModel.Record] = []
    
    @State private var showAddRecord: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navigationPath) {
            List {
                ForEach(modelView.currentData) { record in
                    NavigationLink(value: record, label: { Text(record.timeDate) })
                }.onDelete(perform: { index in
                    index.forEach({ i in
                        modelView.deleteRecord(i)
                    })
                })
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: JournalRecordsModel.Record.self) { record in
                RecordDetailedView(record: record, navigationPath: $navigationPath).environmentObject(modelView)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Your Records")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                showAddRecord.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
            }))
            .sheet(isPresented: $showAddRecord) {
                AddRecordView(showAddRecord: self.$showAddRecord).environmentObject(modelView)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> 

```
struct AddRecordView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var modelView : JournalRecordsModelView
    @Binding var showAddRecord: Bool
    @State private var showSubmitAddAlert: Bool = false
    @State private var dateTime = Date.now
    @State private var title: String = ""
    @State private var content: String = ""
    @State private var feeling: String = "Nil"
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Add Record")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .frame(
                    width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2.2,
                    height: 20,
                    alignment: .leading
                ).padding([.leading])
            Button(action : {
                showAddRecord.toggle()
            },
                   label: {
                Image(systemName: "xmark")
            }).frame(
                width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2.2,
                height: 20,
                alignment: .trailing
             )
            .padding([.trailing])
        }.padding([.top, .bottom])
        
        DatePicker("Date and Time", selection: $dateTime)
            .padding(.horizontal)
        
        TextField("Entry Name", text: $title)
            .padding(.horizontal)
        
        TextField("What are your thoughts today?", text: $content)
            .padding(.horizontal)
        
        Text("How are you feeling?")
            .font(.body)
            .padding(.horizontal)
        
        Picker("How do you feel?", selection: $feeling) {
            ForEach(modelView.currentFeelings, id: \.self) { feeling in
                Text(feeling)
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
        
        Spacer()
        Button {
            modelView.addRecord(dateTime, title, content, feeling)
            showSubmitAddAlert.toggle()
        }
        label: {
                Image(systemName: "doc.fill.badge.plus")
        }
        .disabled(title.isEmpty || content.isEmpty || feeling == "Nil")
        .alert("Record added. Please confirm addition of record.", isPresented: $showSubmitAddAlert) {
            //the moment i click OK on the alert, have constraints error, button is causing the error
            **Button("Ok", role: .cancel) {
                showAddRecord.toggle()
            }**
        }
    }
}
```

The button in AddRecordView seems to be causing the problem but I am not sure as to why it is causing the problem. The UI and the app does not crash when running even though the error pops out. I would appreciate any advices in advance. Thank you.

I have checked on all variable names and checked any modifiers for my views that are related to sizing of the views, as I assume that the error is related to dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Message you are seeing is more a hint/warning as an error. There are constraints that do conflict and as the messeages tells you, it will solve this by breaking one constraint. This is not a huge deal, but could lead the UI to not look like you want it to look. You should check the layoutConstraint system anyways to know what is going on here. The listed constraints are system constraints, so it will be hard to figure out by checking them.
What you could try is:

```
**Button("Ok", role: .cancel) {
   showSubmitAddAlert = false
   showAddRecord = false
}**
```

this should close the alert before closing the presented AddRecordView
Also I would recommend setting the bools explicitly to true/false, because in every case there should be no scenario where it is toggled the other way around (makes it much easier to read, and also prevents unwanted behaviour if the value is not set as it should be).

Comment: I'm getting the same constraint message but it seems to be related to the TextField. Once I enter text and go to the next TextField, the error shows up before I even tap my submit button. My app still works as expected but it doesn't like something about the TextField. Did you find a resolution to this?

Comment: I am seeing this in my app on TextField, and as soon as I select the field to enter a value, the view navigates away